# How to use Resource Dictionary by its Key?

Tags: wpf, resourcedictionary

I am trying to use my `Resource Dictionary` but it does not recognize the styles  have created.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <RoutedUICommand x:Key="Add" Text="Add" />
    <RoutedUICommand x:Key="Cancel" Text="Cancel" />
    <RoutedUICommand x:Key="Exit" Text="Exit" />
    <ResourceDictionary x:Key="LightTheme" Source="/Themes/Light.xaml"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

When I delete `x:Key` from ResourceDictionary tag, it shows a message saying "**Each dictionary must have an associated key**"

But when I try to use one of my styles, it does not work.

```
<Button x:Name="AddNew" Style="{StaticResource RoundCorner}">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Merge the dictionary. To do that, you need to have an explicit `ResourceDictionary` element.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Themes/Light.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

        <RoutedUICommand x:Key="Add" Text="Add" />
        <RoutedUICommand x:Key="Cancel" Text="Cancel" />
        <RoutedUICommand x:Key="Exit" Text="Exit" />

    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```